# Calculate $\int_{4}^7 f(x)f(2x) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Actually I am getting confused about the step of an integration.

Suppose \begin{align}f(x) = \begin{cases} x,  \ \ \ 4 \leq x < 7\\\ 0, \ \ \ \text{otherwise}\end{cases}\end{align}

Now I want to calculate $\int_{4}^7 f(x)f(2x) dx = \int_4^7 x \cdot 0 dx = 0\ \ \ \text{(because}\ 8 \leq 2x < 14,\ \text{so}\  f(2x) = 0\ \text{in}\ [4, 7))$.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are absolutely correct. When $x \in (4,7)$, you have that $ 2x \in (8, 14)$, which means that $f(x) f(2x) = 0$ for $x\in (4,7)$. This implies that $\int_4^7 f(x) f(2x)\, dx = 0$.

note: the extreme points in the interval are irrelevant in terms of the value of the integral.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since the integration is wrt $x$  in the interval $(4,7)$, we can calculate the value of $f(x)$ and $f(2x)$ together. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that is it. It may be easier to understand if you just  write that $f(x) f(2x) = g(x)$, and $g(x)$ turns out to be zero in that specific interval.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to calculate $f(2x)$
$$f(2x)=\begin{cases} 
      2x & 4\leq 2x < 7 \\
      0 & otherwise 
   \end{cases}$$
$$f(2x)=\begin{cases} 
      2x & 2\leq x < \frac{7}{2} \\
      0 & otherwise 
   \end{cases}$$

$$\int_{4}^7 f(x)f(2x) dx =\int_4^7x\times 0.dx=\int_4^70.dx=0$$